# MSAL - How to get ID token using Angular 13 compatible MSAL Library

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We are using "MSAL Angular 13" compatible library for Azure AD Authentication. By Default, it passes Access Token.

In my project, we need to pass ID Token not Access token. How to get ID Token? MSAL has one service but there is no methods like "Acquired"IDTone", the way we have 3 methods for getting Access tokens.

We just got a link for ID token but the same is through java script. We will try and see, if something can be done(Not seen the details).

Any pointers would be very heplful.

thanks and best regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Its a very simple question. How to access ID token using MSAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the idToken property of the authResponse object.

https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/docs/msal/modules/_authresponse_.html

All acquireToken() methods return an id_token.

Comment: I will check that where I can get that. We also have "AuthenticationResult" but that is accessible, when we click the login button. But we are using SSO so we would not be able to use.

Comment: SSO is only happening because you call MSAL to begin with, an authResult is always returned in all cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I will check.